# How to return value from an Async function inside React Native FlatList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-flatlist

**I am trying to filter out posts from blocked users. **

I made an async function to check if a user is blocked or not:

```
checkBlocked = async userId => {
  try {
  let snapshot = await firebase.database().ref('Blocked/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userId).once('value')
    return snapshot.exists();
  }
  catch(error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I want to return the value inside flatlist so that accordingly the post shows up there:-

```
<FlatList
        inverted
        extraData={this.state.blocked}
        data={this.state.arrData}
        keyExtractor={item => item.key}

        renderItem={({ item }) => {
         
         
          this.checkBlocked(item.id).then(val => this.setState({blocked: val}));
         
            if(this.state.blocked == true){
              return (
              //something
                 )
            }

          else {
             
          return (
            //something
                 )
            }
         }}
```

**The above approach is not working, where am I going wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

We don't have all the details exactlty, but I can see the logic flow here is strange.  Let's look at what's happening

1. `FlatList` renders with `this.state.arrData`
2. On each iteration of `renderItem`, `checkBlocked` makes an async call with the id of a user
3. You render something based on `this.state.blocked`
4. Your `checkBlocked` promise resolves, and the `blocked` variable in state is overwritten with the returned value

You are making a promise (`checkBlocked(id).then()`), but your `render` does not wait for that promise to resolve before it returns something.  So your `this.state.blocked` is not yet defined as what you think in your return statement.  *Also*, `setState` is *async*, meaning you can't rely on the value in your `return` statements to be the value you just set from `checkBlocked`.

A better pattern would be to that before you render your component, run your userlist through an async loop, where each entry is checked with `checkBlocked`.  You can then construct an array of objects, say `usersWithBlockedStatus`, each object with a user name and blocked status.  Then you filter out all entries who's `blocked` status is true, and call it `usersThatAreNotBlocked`.  Only once all this is complete, you render your `FlatList` with the data as `usersThatAreNotBlocked`.

You can find another well written explanation in the question [How to call fetch() inside renderItem on FlatList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834706/how-to-call-fetch-inside-renderitem-on-flatlist)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I made a separate array of blocked users in componentDidMount and then checked whether the user id exists in the blocked users array, if not print the posts. Thank you so much, i was able to think of this approach just because of you!

Comment: Happy to help .